# When was $e$ first observed to not be a Liouville number?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request

When and by who was it first observed that the [transcendental number $e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) is NOT a [Liouville number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number)?

This fact is stated in a lot of web pages, and a proof can be found in the Mathematics Stack Exchange question [Why is $e$ not a Liouville number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946535/why-is-e-not-a-liouville-number), but I have yet to find any nontrivial historical information about this fact.

I suspect this can be found in Édmond Maillet’s 1906 book [**Introduction à la Théorie des Nombres Transcendants et des Propriétés Arithmétiques des Fonctions**](https://archive.org/details/introductionlat00mailgoog) (where the phrase “Liouville number” was first coined) or in Oskar Perron’s 1913 book [**Die Lehre von den Kettenbrüchen**](https://archive.org/details/dielehrevondenk00perrgoog), but my very poor French and my non-existent German stands in the way.

I began wondering about this when I came across some remarks on this topic in the following 1916 Master of Arts thesis:

Jewell Constance Hughes [*after 1935*: Jewell Hughes Bushey] (1896-1989), [**Transcendentalism of Curves and of Numbers**](https://mospace.umsystem.edu/xmlui/handle/10355/49197), Master of Arts thesis (under Wilhelmus David Allen Westfall, 1879-1951), University of Missouri, 1916, 24 pages.

> **(first paragraph on p. 17)** As we have already explained, in 1844 ["1873" intended] Hermite first showed that $e$ is not algebraic by proving that it cannot satisfy an algebraic equation of degree $m.$ Is it not possible to prove the same thing by showing that $e$ cannot satisfy the Liouville inequality? The following results show the efforts of the writer attacking the problem. This Chapter may be regarded as a preliminary report on an investigation of rather far reaching character which the writer hopes to carry further after this year.
>
> **(last paragraph on p. 24)** As we said in the beginning, this Chapter is a preliminary report of an investigation which the writer hopes to carry on later. We have not been able to prove that $e$ violates the Liouville inequality. Perhaps it does do so, perhaps it does not. Perhaps $e$ is one of an uncountable class of numbers which fail to violate Liouville's Theorem. At the present time we do not know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you guessed, the observation is in Maillet’s 1906 book: Introduction (p. iii), footnote (p. 27) and Corollary II<sub>6</sub> ([p. 125](https://archive.org/stream/introductionlat00mailgoog#page/n148); [Jahrbuch credit](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?37.0237.02)). He announced it earlier in *Comptes Rendus* ([1905](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?36.0444.01), [p. 419](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3095m/f419)):

> $\smash{e^{\frac1q}}$ ($q$ integer $\geqslant 1$) is not a Liouville number

and gave himself credit in the *Encyclopédie* ([1910](https://books.google.com/books?id=QMdJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA288-IA1), [p. 383](https://books.google.com/books?id=QMdJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA383)). The observation doesn't seem to be in Perron’s 1913 *Lehre von den Kettenbrüchen* ([§33](https://archive.org/stream/dielehrevondenk00perrgoog#page/n155)), but it is in his 1921 *Irrationalzahlen* ([§47](https://archive.org/stream/irrationalzahlen00perruoft#page/174)):

> In any case, the number $e$ does not belong to the known types of transcendental numbers: it is not a Liouville number; for its continued fraction expansion, which we derived in §32, obviously does not satisfy the condition of Proposition 71. (...)